# Migrating to IIS 7 from IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-6

I am planning to migrate our windows 2003 server (with IIS 6) to windows 2008 (with IIS7). I have found that with this msdeploy [migration tool](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/18/how-to-migrate-from-iis-6-to-iis-7.aspx). With this tool can export my websites package on to newer machine, but the problem is I have hundreds of virtual directories in IIS6 which are not necessary now, since I am using asp.net routing feature with new IIS7;I don't want to move all the crappy virtual directories on the new machine and take advantage of new features.
I am not able to find any solution to do this cleanly, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably quicker to migrate the lot and script the removal of virtual directories in IIS7 that you no longer require, and then modify the web.config for Asp.net4 routing.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the only choice.